# Mystery Print Separator Page

Tags: printing, aix

Good morning!  After a recent site upgrade to WebSphere 7.0 from 6.1 on an AIX server, our users reported a print separator page appearing on a certain type of report, and only on one printer.  Trouble is, no one (devs, sysadmins, users) knows where it came from or where to turn it off.

Based on the info, the first step was to check the app, but we don't have print separators in our code.  The report they're using also lacks even an option to separate.  Then I asked the WebSphere gurus but they shook their heads.  Ditto the network/print server team.

If anyone can identify the source of this separator, I can take that back to the relevant team and have it switched off.  They look like this (some whitespace removed for brevity):

```
*##################################################
*##################################################
*##################################################

***************************************************
TITLE:          [document name]
TIME PRINTED:   Fri Sep 20 08:21:45 2013
TIME QUEUED:    Fri Sep 20 08:21:45 2013
PRINTED AT:     hp@hp41 (generic) @ [app name]
SUBMITTED BY:   root
DELIVER TO:     =====> root <=====

***************************************************
FLAG VALUES:
a-0, b=0, d=a, f=, g=1, h=, i=0, j=+, l=00, p=10, t=0, v=6, w=3--, x=2, A=1,
B=gn, C=!, H=, J=+, L=+, N=1, P=[printer name]:hp@hp41, X=ISO8859-1, Z=+,
0=ibm.850

***************************************************
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://marc.info/?l=aix-l&m=96428030128058&w=2) (and click to ["next in thread"](http://marc.info/?l=aix-l&m=96428030128059&w=2)) it is a header from `lpr`. I don't know AIX but perhaps you can configure the print command (which uses `lpr`) somewhere to use `lpr -h`.

> You're probably using the "lpr" command which generates a header unless
>   "lpr -h" is used.  You could use another command, enq, qprt, lp, etc.
>   Or, you could use lsvirprt to blank out the contents of the sh
>   attribute, making the queue incapable of generating a header.

I don't know if the following PDF applies to your system but there is also mention of setting a `header` line to `never`. Maybe with this information (and the `lpr -h` bit) the developers/sysadmins can track down the sender of the header.

[Printing for Fun and Profit Under AIX V4](http://ps-2.kev009.com/rs6000/redbook-cd/gg243570.pdf) (just search for `header` in the PDF)